# Randomly assign 3 variables

Tags: random, logic

I have 3 variables, a,b and c, and want to randomly assign them 3 possible numbers, 1,2 or 3. a may equal b but c may not equal either. 
So if a = 2 and = 1, then c = 3.
If a = 1 and b = 1, then c must be either 2 or 3(randomly).

Currently I do:
a and b = random values. Then:

```
if (a == b)
{
    do 
    {
        c = (int)(Math.random()*3); 
    } while (c == a);
} else
{
    do
    {
        c = (int)(Math.random()*3); 
    }while (c == a || c == b);
}
```

Is this the best way? How else would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Making a call to generate a random number is the most expensive thing you are doing here, so you should do it as little as possible (two or three times).

(2) You should probably prefer `java.util.Random`, particularly if you want `int`s.

```
java.util.Random random = new java.util.Random();
int a = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
int b = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
int c = 0;
for(int n = a == b ? random.nextInt(2) : 0; n >= 0; n--) {
    do {
      c++;
    } while(c == a || c == b);
}
```

This will be "uniformly" random.

**Explanation:**

We first choose `a` and `b` randomly from the three choices. We are left with either one or two choices for `c`, depending whether `a` equals `b`. We "roll the dice" for `c` and find the spot where `c` fits in.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign a value to the `c` at first, and then based on that, randomly assign other variables:

```
c = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
do 
{
   a = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
} while(a == c);
do
{
   b = random.nextInt(3) + 1;
} while(b == c);
```